# Render Image from Rich Text Field

Tags: apex, visualforce, images

I have a rich text field where users can attach images. I am displaying these images in a visualforce page. When I am rendering the images, I am not getting the images. Instead, the image is getting rendered as html text.

Here's my apex code:

```
public List<SObject> getResults () {
    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    List<SObject> results = [SELECT Id, 
                                    Name, 
                                    URL__c,
                                    Filename__c,
                                    Screenshot__c
                                    FROM myCustomObject__c 
                                    WHERE parent__c = :id];
    return results;
}
```

And here's my visualforce:

```
<apex:repeat var="v" value="{! results }">
      <div class="styleclass">
          {! v.Name}
      </div>
      <h3>Screenshot</h3>
      <div class="styleclass">
          {! v.Screenshot__c}
      </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

v.Screenshot__c is giving me something like this:

> `<p><img src="https://mydomain.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=imageid&amp;feoid=someid&amp;refid=someid" alt="myimage.png"></img><img src="https://mydomain.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=imageid&amp;feoid=someid&amp;refid=someid" alt="anotherimage.png"></img></p>`

Instead of this, how can I render an actual image.

Appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `<apex:outputField>` tag instead of a naked merge field.

Incorrect:

```
<div>{!myRecord.MyField__c}</div>
```

Correct:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!myRecord.MyField__c}" />
```